# Pom.xml that run only in Windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, maven, pom.xml

This is my configuration in my pom.xml to run the script flip.cmd:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>My test</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>${basedir}/flip.cmd</executable>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

It works fine in my Windows PC, the problem is that I should be able to run the same in Linux.

How should I change the above configuration in order to run on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: It looks fine. What happens when you try to build it on Linux?

Comment: @Danio My guess is that `flip.cmd` is a batch file so it simply won't work on Linux.

Comment: yes, that's correct Tunaki. It's a batch file for Windows. But if I put a *.sh instead, it will only work in Linux and not in Windows. That's the dilemma

Comment: You'll have to write an equivalent script for Linux and point to it using the correct path.

Answer (score 4):

You must prepare another script executable in Linux shell (e.g. *.sh) and then create separate profiles activated by OS

```
<profile>
    <id>windows</id>
    <activation>
        <os>
            <family>windows</family>
        </os>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>My test</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${basedir}/flip.cmd</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>unix</id>
    <activation>
        <os>
            <family>unix</family>
        </os>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>My test</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${basedir}/flip.sh</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```